# Slow query due to planer invalid stats - even after analyze

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sf.dir_current (
    id BIGINT primary key,
    volume_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    path VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
CREATE index dir_volid_path_indx on dir_current (volume_id, path);

CREATE TABLE sf.event (
    id BIGINT,  -- no primary key here!
    volume_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parent_path VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    type BIGINT, 
    depth INTEGER
);
```

Table dir contains ~50 millions of rows and in all rows volume_id = 1. Table events contains ~20K rows.

I execute following query (in PLSQL function - VOL_ID, MIN_ID, MAX_ID and so on are function params):

```
select dir.id as parent_id, event as event_row
        from sf.event as event
            left outer join sf.dir_current as dir on dir.volume_id = VOL_ID and parent_path = dir.path
        where event.volume_id = VOL_ID
            and event.id between MIN_ID and MAX_ID
            and (DEPTH_FILTER is null or event.depth = DEPTH_FILTER)
            and (TYPE_FILTER is null or event.type = TYPE_FILTER)
        order by event.depth;
```

Everything works fine when all rows in dir table has volume_id = 1. After adding few thousand rows with volume_id = 2 (and running analyze) this query takes very long. 
Here is explain of long running query: [explain.depesz.com](https://explain.depesz.com/s/3QmX)

As it is clearly visible query planner had no idea that there are so many rows with volume_id = 2 and created plan far from optimal.

After some debugging I found out that analyze did not find any row with volume_id = 2. I confirmed it with query:

```
starfish=# SELECT most_common_vals, n_distinct FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'dir_current' and attname = 'volume_id';

 most_common_vals | n_distinct 
------------------+------------
 {1}              |          1
(1 row)
```

After few analyze's it finnally finds some values with vol_id = 2 and query gets back to normal execution time: [explain.depesz.com](https://explain.depesz.com/s/vwBf)

Question: how to prevent extremely long query time? Is there a way to force analyze to find this rows? Or maybe manually modify stats for this column (setting n_distinct for vol_id column does not help).

I'm using Postresql 9.5

Comment: as per http://ask.use-the-index-luke.com/questions/162/how-can-i-influence-the-postgres-planner-to-always-do-a-bitmap-index-scanbitmap-heap-scan-instead-of-an-index-scan try increasing working memory and increasing statistics target?..

Comment: Unfortunately increasing statistics target does not guarantee success it only increase a chance for success. Working memory is already high enough.

Comment: try using `CTE`?.. In same article guy sugests isolating query with wanted where clause on the index you want, so then join would pickup your chosen index. I did try myself but I understood you can make planner use index1 if you `with hack as (select index1_column from table where index1_column = 'some value') select * from hack join table2 on etc`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.